# Trigger jQuery script to run if browser window is resized

Tags: jquery, resize

I have a script that removes and class if the browser width is under 800px (it removes a sticky script to keep a menu at the top of the page). It works fine if you open the page at the correct browser width or resize the browser and then refresh (to trigger the script again) - but I was wondering if there is something I can add to the script to make it trigger automatically if the browser window is resized?

```js
$(function() {
 'use strict';
 if ($(window).width() < 800) {
  $('#mainNav').removeClass('navStick');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(window).resize(functionName);`
https://api.jquery.com/resize/

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 800) {
        $('#mainNav').removeClass('navStick');
    }
});
```